# Excel - conditional value or drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am designing a dynamic request form in Excel, and basically, I'm trying to achieve:

=IF(AND(C11>=100,C11<=500,"Option A",[Choose from a drop down list]))

In other words, if the value of C11 is greater than or equal to 100 and less than or equal to 500, the result is Option A, otherwise the user chooses from a drop down list of other options.

Can anyone suggest how I would go about this? Would I need VBA? I have tried similar solutions but have had no luck thus far with data validation and drop downs at the same time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not have a drop down and a formula at the same time in the same cell.  You will need vba in a worksheet change event that either puts the value or creates the data validation.

Comment: Or put the drop down in another adjacent column and then in the cell use a formula to either put in the fixed value or the value from the drop down depending on the criteria.

Comment: Are you looking for dependent Drop-down list in Excel?